# SLOC tool for java with man-years estimation

Tags: java

I'm looking for a tool to count source lines of code for Java as well as giving an estimate of the number of man-years invested in the code. Since Java code tends to be more verbose than other languages, with a lot of boilerplate code (anemic beans) generated by the IDE, I want the tool's metric to take this into account.

If someone can just provide the formula to convert source line count to man years (for java), this is also good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/ is the best bet.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a really bad idea.

The best way to estimate the number of man years work on a piece of code it to look at who worked on it and how long.

Trying to infer this man years from SLOC is likely to be highly inaccurate and misleading. For example:

- At some point in the software lifecycle many lines of code can be added. In some periods of maintenance / refactoring code may be actually taken away.
- Code that has had a lot of requirements changes and quick hacks is likely to have more SLOC than equivalent code that was cleanly designed and written in the first place.
- The same functionality can be written with 100 lines or 1000 lines depending on the libraries / frameworks used.
- Are you going to count SLOC in libraries too? What about the JVM? What about the underlying OS?

In short, any estimate of man years derived from SLOC is likely to be pretty meaningless.

Comment: I want to compare the actual invested time vs the amount as estimated by a metric. E.g. if time invested is 1 man year and metric says 3, then we're in excellent shape. If time invested is 3 man years and metric says 1, then we're in bad shape (even if it means a lot of code was deleted, this is still a bad sign). Obviously, this is a very rough estimate.

Comment: That is exactly why this is a bad idea. You estimate will be so unreliable that it might tell you that you are in good shape when in fact you are in bad shape (or vice versa). It won't really help anybody to do this kind of analysis. e.g. having had a lot of code deleted means that at least someone is actively maintaining the code base which is probably a *good* sign.

Answer (score 1):

Although you want the information for bad purposes SLOC is a nice, easy, not very useful metric. Make sure you read [this older conversation first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143084/code-complexity-analysis-tools-beyond-cyclomatic-complexity)

Answer (score 0):

> One of my most productive days was throwing away 1000 lines of
>   code.(Kent beck).

It is not going to be accurate for various reasons. Some from my experience ..

- Code gets added , changed or deleted:  If you really want query your
  SCM for change history and then map to changed lines.
- Architectural changes/Introducing a library replacing your code. : In
  our case it reduced    Coding only part of the change: Design
  discussions, client interactions, documentation etc will not be
  reflected in code, even though I consider they are development effort
- Finally developers are f varying productivity (1 : 40 , some said):
  How are you going to map into developer time?

SLOC is a useful tool to say my code base it 'this large' or 'this small'..

Answer (score 0):

at the office i use [ProjectCodeMeter](http://www.ProjectCodeMeter.com) to estimate man-years invested in a source code, it's kind of a luxury tool at that price, but i did use the free trial version at home on occasions :)