# Is there a way to determine the general cost function of an arbitrary java method?

Tags: java

I'm interested to know if there already exists an approach that takes java method code as an input and determines the cost function of such code (number of loops, ifs/elses, I/Os and other common things). 
I mean not the exact cost in ms but some general cost that this code may cause.
The thing is that I want to be able for the arbitrary method that user writes to say what can be the the cost of such method (of course not taking into accounts some specificities like the JVM etc.).

Comment: This question deals with a deep problem in static analysis and in general the solutions are going to be so approximate they might not really work for the cases you care about (read, static analysis is hard).  If you gave a little more background as to *why* you want this, you might be able to get more refined answers as to the tools you can use.

Comment: Many super-cool algorithms require rather sophisticated techniques to prove their asymptotic complexity.  Doing it from the code alone is for all practical purposes impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if such a tool exists, but I doubt both its feasibility and its usability:

- For the feasibility of such a tool in the general case have a look at the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is a significant part of what you are asking for and has been proven to be [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).
- For the usability of such a tool, I believe that static code analysis on its own is useless, because a significant part of the performance of a system depends on its *usage patterns*, i.e. on its input.

  There is a reason that even benchmarking systems at *runtime* is not straight-forward; the same software could be amazingly fast in some cases and staggeringly slow in others.

That said, there are [several tools for code complexity analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143084/507519), but those metrics focus on structural complexity, which relates more to quality and maintainability than performance.

Answer (score 1):

For number of loops, if/elses you can employ cyclomatic complexity metric. There are tools to calculate it. For instance, [JavaNCSS](http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/). Regarding other things, you should decide what exactly you are interested in. There are a lot of [software metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_metric) and some of them may be suitable for you. If not, you can invent yours and implement them. Say, [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) - another popular tool for gathering different metrics - allows you to write your own rules.

If you'd like to automatically predict performance of your code then you are out of luck. Reasons are pointed by thkala, others include JVM JIT compilation and runtime optimizations. Your best friends here are profiling, (automated) performance testing and algorithm analysis. Static analysis can show you *some* potential performance problems like concatenating strings or allocating objects in a loop. Modern IDEs are able to do this. Still, performance mostly is determined by algorithms and architecture, so you hardly will get much improvements on the way of static analysis.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes I know that structural complexity will not give me the real cost but I want to start from there and then see what else I need to take into account. I'll study these links and see what can I do.